# x11-common contains empty filename

Tags: debian, x11, software-installation

I can't update, upgrade or install anything at the moment because I get an error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
files list file for package 'x11-common' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I have tried to fix it but no success with that one. Also tried to reinstall but that failed with the same error. Is there anyway to fix this or am I doomed? I'm running Debian 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message means that the `/var/lib/dpkg/info/x11-common.list` file was corrupted somehow. To fix this, delete it:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/x11-common.list
```

and then re-install the package:

```
sudo apt --reinstall install x11-common
```

Comment: Thank you that took care of the problem, but for some reason it's trying to uninstall jitsi-meet-prosody also with that second command. I have tried to uninstall that one before without success and in the end I have `error: prosody.service is not active, cannot reload.
invoke-rc.d: initscript prosody, action "reload" failed.
dpkg: error processing package jitsi-meet-prosody (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1`

Comment: I might need to make another seperate question about that one.

Comment: It looks like there’s more stuff broken — the `prosody.service` error is probably the result of the previous removal attempt, and not related to the `x11-common` re-installation. You should indeed ask a separate question...

Comment: Yes, I thought so as well. Thank you for your help!

Comment: when I do this, the same error is reported for new packages without anything reinstalled. So, if originally the problem was `'libedit2:amd64' contains empty filename`, then I did `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libedit2:amd64.list ./` and the `sudo apt --reinstall install libedit2:amd64` breaks with `'libvorbis0a:amd64' contains empty filename` etc.

Comment: @xealits that sounds like you have multiple corrupted `.list` files...

Comment: @StephenKitt you are right! Just now I checked that -- they do not show up as ascii text files.

Comment: Luckily, just a few files were corrupted. I found them with `ls /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list | xargs file | tee corrupt_info_list_files` and `grep 'data$' corrupt_info_list_files` (normally the end of the line must be "ASCII text"). Then one more file had a strange problem: `libllvm8:amd64.list` was ASCII, but instead of a list of file paths it contained a bunch of fields "Language, Hash-Name, Emacsen-Name, Coding-System". I moved this file too and reinstalled `libllvm8:amd64` first. It went well, then the others reinstalled too. A bit puzzled by this issue now.. What was it?

Comment: @xealits that sounds like file system corruption. You might want to run `fsck`...